# Populate temporal SQL DB table with PowerShell using stored procedure with table-valued parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I am learning SQL although familiar with Powershell.

I am trying to call a stored procedure using a table-valued parameter to insert an array of data from PowerShell into a temporal SQL DB table.

I am using the SqlServer PowerShell module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver15

The DB is called "WAGS", the table is called "AzureADUsers" and my user defined type is called "AzureADUser"

The command appears to complete succesfully although I see no data in the table, I am unsure what I am doing wrong, or of this is the correct approach.

My user defined type looks like this (as do the columns in my AzureADUser table).

```html
01: ImmutableId         varchar            255 UNIQUE
02: DisplayName         varchar            255
03: UserPrincipalName   varchar            255 UNIQUE
04: ObjectId            uniqueidentifier       16  UNIQUE
```

My stored procedure looks like this (I have included the entire ALTER script incase I have made a mistake here).

```html
 USE [WAGS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spUpdateAzureADUsersTable]    Script Date: 20/10/2020 15:59:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateAzureADUsersTable] (@users [dbo].[AzureADUser] READONLY)
    AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AzureADUsers]
        (
            ImmutableId,
            DisplayName,
            UserPrincipalName,
            ObjectId
        )
    SELECT * FROM @users
```

I am trying to call the stored procedure using the Invoke-SqlCmd PowerShell cmdlet like so:

```html
$azureAdUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | ? { $_.ImmutableId }

$data = $azureAdUsers | Select ImmutableId,DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,ObjectId

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'MERCURY\SQLEXPRESS' -Database 'WAGS' -QUERY "EXEC spUpdateAzureADUsersTable $data"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Microsoft SQL PowerShell module has many bugs/limitations. The stored procedure, type and table were all created correctly, the issue was how I was calling it from PowerShell using (or rather, how I was passing the array of values).

I ended up dropping down into ADO.NET with Powershell with the help of this chap: http://tomaslind.net/2016/05/27/from-powershell-to-sql-tables/

NOTE: When creating large datatables it is faster to use [void] rather than piping to Out-Null.

My PowerShell now looks like this:

```html
$azureAdUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | ? { $_.ImmutableId }

$dataTable = [System.Data.DataTable]::New()

[void]($dataTable.Columns.Add("ObjectId","System.Guid"))
[void]($dataTable.Columns.Add("ImmutableId","System.String"))
[void]($dataTable.Columns.Add("DisplayName","System.String"))
[void]($dataTable.Columns.Add("UserPrincipalName","System.String"))

foreach($u in $azureAdUsers)
{
    [void]($dataTable.Rows.Add($u.ObjectId,$u.ImmutableId,$u.DisplayName,$u.UserPrincipalName))
}

$ServerInstance = "MERCURY\SQLEXPRESS"

$DatabaseName = "WAGS"
 
$ConnString = "Server=$ServerInstance;Database=$DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnString

$conn.Open()
 
$query = "dbo.spUpdateAzureADUsersTable"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]"StoredProcedure"
$cmd.CommandText = $Query
$cmd.Parameters.Add("@users", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured) | Out-Null
$cmd.Parameters["@users"].Value = $dataTable

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$conn.Close()
```